Software/web service that can extract quoted text and attributions from fiction
I have need of a tool that can read through a (potentially long) work of fiction (e.g. short story, novel, etc) and find instances where a character speaks and provide as output the name of the character and the content of what they say.
I'm aware that this is quite difficult, as in many cases the identity of the speaker must be inferred from context (e.g. in situations where two characters are conversing it is conventional to not name them every time, but just allow the reader to assume they take it in turns to speak), so this is likely to require some kind of AI/machine learning.  I suspect ChatGPT4 can probably be made to do it, but (1) it's quite slow, (2) I don't currently have a subscription to it, and would prefer something a little cheaper, and (3) I suspect something designed specifically for the purpose will probably be more accurate.
Ideally this would be something I could run locally, and bonus points if it's open source and implemented in Python so I can use it on Google Colab, but if worst comes to worst I'll consider commercial/closed-source solutions.  Any suggestions?
